# Convert Lambda Expression Parameter Type

Tags: c#, lambda

If I have the following classes...

```
public class Source
{
  public string Name
  {
    get;

    set;
  }
}

public class Destination
{
  public string Name
  {
    get;

    set;
  }
}
```

...and I have the following code to create an expression....

```
Expression<Func<Source, bool>> expression = e => e.Name == "Test;
```

...what I end up with is a lambda expression with a single parameter (`e`) of type `Source`.  What I am trying to do is convert this expression to have a parameter of type `Destination`.

I have tried something like...

```
Expression<Func<Destination, bool>> expression2 = Expression.Lambda<Func<Destination, bool>>(expression.Body, Expression.Parameter(typeof(Destination), "e")));
```

...but this does not seem to work.

What is the *best* way to make this conversion.  It seems like, from what I recall working with, the inner parts of the expression tree (in this case, the member expression) are bound to a particular type.  Would I need to parse through the entire expression tree in order to make the conversion?  Is there something simple I am missing?

Comment: What is the purpose of what you trying to do?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you mean by conversion? You mean casting or you're trying to change the code that builds the expression?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what you are trying to do. I just understand that you are trying to make your lambda expression to be compatible with `Source` and `Destination` without creating two lambda expressions for each one.

Based on my understand.

First create an Interface like that :

```
public interface IName
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then make `Source` and `Destination` to implement the new interface `IName` as follow:

```
public class Source : IName
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Destination : IName
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then your lambda expression will simply look like this:

```
Expression<Func<IName, bool>> expression = e => e.Name == "Test";
```

this lambda expression is compatible with all class that impelment `IName` interface.

Comment: I agree that this would generally be the best way, but what if either `Source` or `Destination` is third party software?

Comment: Just box/wrap them into another class that implement that interface.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there something simple I am missing?

If fact handling all the possible cases is not simple. A simplified function that supports only property/field accessors of the predicate parameter could be like this

```
public static class ExpressionUtils
{
    public static Expression<Func<TTarget, bool>> Convert<TSource, TTarget>(Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> source)
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TTarget), source.Parameters[0].Name);
        var body = new ParameterConverter { source = source.Parameters[0], target = parameter }.Visit(source.Body);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TTarget, bool>>(body, parameter);
    }

    class ParameterConverter : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        public ParameterExpression source;
        public ParameterExpression target;
        protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
        {
            return node == source ? target : base.VisitParameter(node);
        }
        protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
        {
            return node.Expression == source ? Expression.PropertyOrField(target, node.Member.Name) : base.VisitMember(node);
        }
    }
}
```

And the usage with your sample would be:

```
Expression<Func<Source, bool>> source = e => e.Name == "Test;
var target = ExpressionUtils.Convert<Source, Destination>(source);
```